# Integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon cos x},0\le\varepsilon<1,$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

There is a function as follow:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon \cos x},0\le\varepsilon<1,$$
I tried to use the Newton-Leibniz Formula to solve it.So I tried to seek the indefinite integral of the function.
I knew that if using the integration of substitution and substituting the $\cos x$ with $t$, it will be solved. But that method makes the *condition* no sense. So if there is any director method to evaluate the integral?

Comment: Why would it disrupt the *condition* no matter how it is solved?

Comment: Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3IexrVsaqg.

Comment: If you found an indefinite integral $F_\varepsilon$, with parameter $\varepsilon$, then your function is $\varepsilon \mapsto F_\varepsilon(\frac2\pi) - F_\varepsilon (0)$.

Comment: I have thought that the range of the $\varepsilon$ is used in the seeking of the indefinite integral so I haved thought the condition is useless if I use the substitution method.But having read the answer following, I realized the condition is used to make the $1-\varepsilon\ge 0$ so it can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite the integral in the following way:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{dx}{\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\epsilon\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\epsilon\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

$$ = \int_0^{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{dx}{(1+\epsilon)\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+(1-\epsilon)\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

$$ = \frac{2}{1-\epsilon}\int_0^{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx}{\left(\frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

$$= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos(x)=\frac{1-\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}{1-\tan^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}$ putting this we obtain $\int_0^{\frac{2}{π}}\frac{\sec^2(\frac{x}{2})dx}{1+\varepsilon+ (1-\varepsilon)\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}$ then it is easy if we substitute $\tan(\frac{x}{2})=t$.